# spring cloud vault pull path wrong

Tags: spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have this config for spring cloud vault.
I am trying to pull a kv secret form location `appcodes/AAAA/BBBB/CCCCC`
On starting application I see:

> `RequestedSecret [path='appcodes/data/AAAA/BBBB/CCCCC', mode=RENEW]]`

Can anyone tell me why is `data` being appended to the path?

```
spring:
    cloud:
        vault:
            scheme: https
            host: xxxxxx
            port: 443
            connection-timeout: 5000
            read-timeout: 15000
            authentication: TOKEN
            token: xxxxxxx
            kv:
                enabled: true
                backend: appcodes
                profile-separator: '/'
                default-context: application
                application-name: AAAA/BBBB/CCCCC
```

Answer (score 0):

Vault has two KV secrets engine. In second version `/data` should be added, see
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/kv/kv-v2.html#acl-rules

So Spring Cloud Vault has support for 2 back-ends: generic (v1) and kv (v2). And it does it automatically.

> Spring Cloud Vault adds the data/ context between the mount path and the actual context path.

See more at: 
[Generic Backend Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/single/spring-cloud-vault.html#vault.config.backends.generic), [Versioned Key-Value Backend Documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/single/spring-cloud-vault.html#vault.config.backends.kv.versioned)